Error while downloading file via FetchAPI
I am trying to download PDF from react app using fetchAPI as following :
const testApiURL = "http://localhost:5288/api/files/download/?fileUrl=location/500-KB.pdf";
function clickHandle() {
    fetch(testApiURL, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/pdf", "responseType": "arraybuffer" }
    })
        .then(response => response.blob()
            .then((blob) => {
                const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                // Setting various property values
                let alink = document.createElement("a");
                alink.href = fileURL;
                alink.download = "MyFile.pdf";
                alink.click();
            })
        .catch(error => console.error(error)));
}

REST API returns byteArray , but when when opening downloaded file in Downnloads folders - getting error "File corrupted". After debugging it was found that inspite of that content type provided is "application/pdf" response got as "application/json". What is missing / wrong in the fetch call ? Thanks in advance

that's up to your api to respond with the right content type.

Use FileReader:
...
.then((blob) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    if (!event?.target?.result) {
       return;
    }
    const dataUrl = event.target.result;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = dataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = 'MyFile.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
...


Thanks for reply - after adding this snippet : getting 406 error . Here is API code creating response :  byte[] fileData = _downloadService.DownloadFile(fileUrl);
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", @"application/octect-stream");
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("responseType", "arraybuffer");    I tried in API set content type also as pdf - same error
